# NHibernate sql query without map one column one row

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a settings table without a primary key that I want to be able to select one column/one row from without any mappings.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can still use raw SQL *(underlying DB Engine related)*:

```
var session = ... ; // standard session, with access to other mapped stuff
var sql = "SELECT settingCol FROM dbo.myTable WHERE ... ";
var result = session
    .CreateSQLQuery(sql)
    .UniqueResult<string>(); // or <int>
```

and work with that result without being mapped to any entity. Check the

[17.1. Using an ISQLQuery](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-creating)

Comment: Thank you, I had a solution but it was less elegant, thank you :)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir